# Ant or maven script to download jar files from RTC repository

Tags: maven, ant, rtc

I am trying to write a script which downloads/checkout the jar file from RTC and then store in my local repository. How do i go about it and is there a tutorial which may help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the article "[Using the SCM Command Line Interface in builds](https://jazz.net/library/article/195)", which describes how the SCM Command Line Interface (SCM CLI) allows users to load, commit, and deliver changes from scripts.

It uses the SCM CLI, which can be found in the `jazz/scmtools/eclipse` of any RTC "client" download.
You have examples of loading a sandbox with that CLI in "[Loading Content from a Jazz Source Control Repository in Rational Team Concert 2.0, 3.0 and 3.0.1](https://jazz.net/library/article/192#CLI)".

Instead of the scm, you also can use the specific ant task [`teamFetch`](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/r_teamfetch.html&scope=null).

```
<teamFetch repositoryAddress="${repositoryAddress}"
           userId="${userId}"
           passwordFile="${passwordFile}"
           workspaceUUID="${env.workspaceId}"
           destination="${sourceDir}"
           verbose="true" />
```